# Removing empty groups from barChart using dc.js

Tags: javascript, dc.js

I am having some issues in removing empty groups from a barChart.

My intention is to remove empty groups from the xAxis (to hide them entirely) and have the barChart scale things accordingly.

Having read the dc.js faq I came across this snippet:

```
var group = {
 all:function () {
  return _group.all().filter(function(d) {
   return d.value != 0;
  })
 }
};
```

I have added this code like so:

```
BarChart.on("preRedraw", function(chart) {
  group = chart.group();
  group2 = {
      all: function()
          { return group.all().filter(function(d) { return (d.value.wins+d.value.losses) > 0; } ) }
  };
 chart.group(group2);
})
```

Doing this causes a "too much recursion" error after 1-2 filters on other charts that I use.

group2 provides correct results, but it seems like the existing bars do not get affected by it or do in weird ways causing bars to have gaps or other flaws.

I have tried adding at the end of the function with no success.

```
BarChart.x(d3.scale.ordinal());
BarChart.xUnits(dc.units.ordinal);
BarChart.rescale();
```

I even tried rerendering the chart.

Any help regarding this matter would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want to do this once, while initializing the chart. This kind of fake group is dynamically calculated and doesn't need to be reset on each draw cycle.

In other words, the source `_group` mentioned in the FAQ is intended to be the group you would otherwise have passed to the chart in its initialization, and once you produce the fake group, pass that in instead.

Comment: I see where my mistake was. It stemmed from a google groups discussion I found on a similar subject (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/UERVo4QGX7w). The last reply led me down the wrong path. Thank you for the quick response